Why does my mouse have Parkinson's?
For a while, my mouse pointer has been vibrating as if it had Parkinson's disease, at a frequency of around 3 Hz with a displacement of a few pixels.
I have no clue why it does that. It happens whatever device I use: if I switch off trackpad and just have external mouse connected it shakes. If I switch off my mouse and just use trackpad, it still shakes.
How can I debug this? I have an M1 Pro on macOS Sonoma (14.5), but the problem has been around for a few minor versions at least. If I remember correctly, it's intermittent, it's not always shaking, but when it shakes it shakes for as long as I can remember (during that day).

The shaking is independent of me touching anything. Hands on or off mouse or trackpad, it always shakes (when it shakes)

Update: about 40min after posting this, the shaking has stopped (for now). I disabled a bunch of startup items in preferences. Not sure if that's causal or coincidental.

Could you update the post with a screenshot of System Preferences -> Mouse settings?

Does it vibrate when the trackpad/mouse are not actively being touched?

@IconDaemon yes it does - though it has stopped just now that I'm thinking about it, no clue what's different.
